# Facing type mismatch error in IE8 during jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

[image]

```
 if (document.documentElement.contains ) {
    Sizzle.contains = function( a, b ) {
        return a !== b && (a.contains ? a.contains(b) : true); // error in      
  this line
    };

} 
else if ( document.documentElement.compareDocumentPosition ) {
    Sizzle.contains = function( a, b ) {
        return !!(a.compareDocumentPosition(b) & 16);
    };

} 
else {
    Sizzle.contains = function() {
        return false;
    };
}
```

The commented line is throwing error. when i search something it'll display no result if their is no matching record. and when i clear each character  in text box again it'll start to search. so at that time i'm getting this type mismatch error

Comment: What is your version of jQuery ?

Comment: see i added the snapshot.. of error... jquery- 1.7

Answer (score 0):

`Type mismatch` is a common error of IE8 when it working in a weird mode. You can try this things :

- Check if IE8 is in compatibility mode. If yes, disable it and put it in normal mode
- Check the doctype of you html. It must be `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: thanks for ur reply..ya its in normal mode only. doctype is also html. as u said.